# how to learn web design technics

Tags: jquery, html, css, photoshop

I am a begining Web Designer .I want to learn the most useful methods used in web designing world.  Please tell some tutorials for learn creative website using photoshop, css, html,......

Answer (score 2):

For CSS, anything by Eric Meyer (http://meyerweb.com/) should be good.
For simpler things like HTML, maybe you could get started following tutorials at http://net.tutsplus.com/ and http://w3schools.com/.

Also, you should be a little more specific when asking questions of this type.

Comment: In my opinion w3schools is quite a poor resource, I've found that some of the information it provides is either out of date, or factually incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

I like the [Head Firs](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/)t series by O'Reilly Publishing. They have a few web related ones, I'm already pretty familiar with HTML, CSS, Javascript, so I just got their web design book listed below, but it referenced the XHTML book a lot. So, if you wanted to check out those books you might want to read them in this order:

1. [Head First HTML with CSS & XHTML](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfhtml/)
2. [Head First Web Design](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfwd/)

Then if you're interested in client-side or server-side scripting, maybe these would be good (I haven't read them, but I like the format of the books...not as boring as tech books):

- [Head First Javascript](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfjs/) (client-side script)
- [Head First PHP & MySQL](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfphp/) (server-side script and database)
- [Head First Rails](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfrails/) (server-side scripting language framework for Ruby language)

Anyway, there are also books for Java (which can be run on a web host) and deeper software development related topics as well.

Also, after getting acquainted with javascript a little (maybe from w3schools as @rmk suggested) I'd encourage you to learn the [jQuery javascript framework](http://jquery.com/), which makes writing javascript code much easier, and much more cross-browser friendly.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @rmk's answer, above, it's worth taking a look at Stu Nicholl's website: [CSS Play](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/) for CSS techniques and implementation wizardry.

Other than that, I think you'd be best off finding something that you'd like to achieve with html/css/js/etc, and then asking specific questions as regards how to implement it.

Comment: +1 for stu nicholls... nice :)

Comment: @downvote, Would the mysterious down-voter care to explain?